# real analyis exam review

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a bounded function on [a, b]. Show that the functions defined by:

m(x) = inf{ f($\zeta$): $\zeta \in$ [a, x)}

is continuous from the left on (a, b)

I've review the topics and I am not entirely sure how to prove something is continuous from the left on an open interval.  Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: *how to prove something is continuous from the left on an open interval*... Take any $x$ such that $a\lt x\lt b$ and show that $\lim\limits_{y\to x,y\lt x}m(y)=m(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x_0\in(a,b)$. To show that $m$ is continuous from the left at $x_0$, you must show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|m(x)-m(x_0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $x_0-\delta<x<x_0$. HINT: Show that $m$ is monotone non-increasing.

Comment: just a question: does |m(x)−m(x0)|< ϵ have to be strictly less than epsilon? according to Strichartz, to show f is continuous from the left, the absolute value (seen above) should be less than or equal to epsilon.

Comment: @user76215: It makes no difference: if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $|m(x)-m(x_0)|\le\epsilon$ whenever $x_0-\delta_\epsilon<x<x_0$, then taking $x_0-\delta_{\epsilon/2}<x<x_0$ ensures that $|m(x)-m(x_0)|<\epsilon$.